# JWT Refresh Token. Одновременная авторизация в МП и на сайте

Tags: jwt

Пишу API для фронта сайта и МП(Мобильное приложение).
Авторизация происходит через JWT токены.
Соответственно апи выдает обычный токен со сроком жизни 1ч
и Refresh Token - одноразовый долгоживущий токен - 2мес.
Возник вопрос касательно одновременной авторизации и на сайте и в МП:

Авторизация в любом из этих ресурсов привет к обновлению рефреш токена и как следствие в другом ресурсе (сайт\мп) токен станет недействительным. Авторизация продержится максимум 1ч и дальше снова потребует логин\пароль для новой пары токенов.

Можно ли как-то обойти эту ситуацию? Какие возможны варианты.

Т.е. пользователь авторизовался и в МП и на сайте - не потребуется вводить логин\пароль через максимум 1ч.

P.S. Я понимаю, что рефреш токен должен быть одноразовым. Из возможных решений пока вижу - это генерацию отдельных рефреш токенов для мп и сайта. В данные рефреш токенов добавить fingerprin и сравнивать их с тем, откуда прилетел запрос(т.е. рефреш токен будет работать только для того источника, для которого он был выдан - мп или сайт)

Comment: сервер авторизации какой используете?

Comment: А почему при аторизации предыдущий токен становится недействительным. может я хочу с нескольких устройств одновременно подключиться и/или из нескольких браузеров/режимов инкогнито

Comment: в данном случае под авторизацией имел в виду первый вход с вводом логина\пароля . Предыдущий токен становится недействительным - это касается только refresh токена т.к. генерируется новый и старый в бд перезаписываем новым. обычный токен - будет работать положенные свои 1ч

Comment: вы можете сделать хранение не одного рефреша, а нескольких с ключам ресурса ('web', 'android', 'iphone'), если пришел рефреш от приложения – смотреть по ключу приложения рефреш-токен. Или вы можете делать выдачу пары токенов не на ресурс, а отдельным OPID сервисом, который выдает пары и который авторизовывает юзера... то есть и сайт и приложуха будут ходить в этот сервис за JWT токеном

Comment: Вы для себя сначала идеологически решите позволяете ли вы например одному пользователю использовать два мобильных устройства одновременно ну и так же позволяете ли входить из двух браузеров одновременно. Если хотя бы на один вопрос ответ "да", то сессии в БД должны храниться отдельно от пользователей и рефреш токен это атрибут сессии, а не пользователя. Ну а дальше уже решайте накладываете ли вы какие то ограничения на количество сессий одного пользователя. Обычно количество сессий на пользователя не ограничивают вообще